# Compute the integral $I=\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz$, where $f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2-6z}$ and $\gamma=\{z:|z-2|=3\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Compute the integral $I=\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz,\ $ where $f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2-6z}$ and $\gamma=\{z:|z-2|=3\}$.

I thought of using $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\frac{f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$

Rewriting $$\int_\gamma\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2-6z}=\int_\gamma\frac{e^{z^2}}{z(z-6)}=\int_\gamma\frac{\frac{e^{z^2}}{z}}{(z-6)} $$

The circumference $\gamma$ determines the domain in which we want the function $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z}$ to operate, which contains $(z-6)$.

So the applying the Cauchy formula:

$$\int f(z)\,dz=\pi i\frac{e^{6^2}}{3} $$

However the solution states the value of integral is $\frac{-\pi i}{3}\cdot$

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point $z=0$ is contained in the contour $\{z:|z-2|\le3\}$ and thus the integral is equivalent to $$2\pi i\,{\rm{Res}}_{z=0} zf(z)=2\pi i\cdot\frac{e^{0^2}}{0-6}=-\frac{\pi i}3.$$ The point $z=6$ is outside this contour so it is not a singularity that concerns us in this question.

---

The correct step in your working should be $$\int_\gamma\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2-6z}\,dx=\int_\gamma\frac{\frac{e^{z^2}}{z-6}}{z}\,dz=2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{z^2}}{z-6}\right)\bigg|_{z=0}$$ from which the same result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not understanding the reason why one can take $z=0$. What is the reason? Where does that come from? What is Res? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but I have not studied residue-calculus yet.

Comment: It is because $|0-2|\le3$ but $|6-2|=4$ is not. If a singularity is outwith the contour we don't care about it. Res stands for Residue, which is essentially what you have computed for $z=6$. It basically evaluates the function at that singularity, multiplied by the singularity factor which usually takes the form $(z-a)^k$. Here, $a=0$ and $k=1$ as it is a simple pole.

Comment: That has to do with the fact that the Cauchy formula derivation implies the disc radius goes to 0? So I can pick any point inside the disc right?

Comment: At a singularity, we take a radius of a small $\epsilon>0$. You choose the points inside the disc for which the function is undefined.